# How to open .xmi files

Tags: file-format, xml

Is there any app that can open `.xmi` files in Ubuntu?

File created in the XMI (XML Metadata Interchange) format, an XML file format most commonly used for exchanging UML diagrams; stores model design information in a standard XML format used for transferring design information between software programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know in the repository `dia` would be closest thing to use since it helps make diagrams (including UML based ones) but I didn't see the .xmi extension as a file it can open.

I have not been able to find another diagram program on the Ubuntu repository that says it can open up a .xmi file ( used this list to do searches on them on Ubuntu 12.04: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UML_tools )

When looking around, I found this link that explains what the file extension means and what programs can open it.

http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/xmi

Two applications were mentioned, Magic MagicDraw (which does not run in Linux) and

### Eclipse IDE for Java Developers with GMF plug-in

`sudo apt-get install eclipse`

http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/gmp/?project=gmf-tooling

Hope this gets you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Umbrello v2.9.5 will open version 1.4 XMI files, but not version 2 format of xmi files - you can install it via the Ubuntu Software Centre.

Personally, I wouldn't use xmlcopyeditor or conglomerate to view XMI files unless you want to view the underlying XML - I'm presuming that you want to view rendered UML diagrams not the textual/XML representions of them.

Answer (score 0):

XMI is a subset of XML, so a text-editor should work, and depending on the type of XMI files, XML viewers might work.  Firefox works on some files, for instance.  okular has plugins for a lot of files -- you might try that if you haven't.

If you interested are interested in doing more than viewing, you might want to look into converters, so that another tool can do the job.  (So a standard XML tool would work.)

On a slightly more picky note, I see that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199504/convert-an-xmi-file-to-xml-file-using-python indicates that it is preferable to call an XMI to XML conversion an XML "transformation", since XMI is (a type of) XML.

`xmlcopyeditor` and `conglomerate` are two XML editors in the repositories (and software center), which you might try if you haven't.